# Apache Ignite 2.5 Plugin implementation

Tags: plugins, ignite

I am trying to implement a custom plugin. I followed an instructions in Ignite tutorial and added a property to the default-config.xml configuration file :

```
 <property name="pluginConfigurations">
          <bean class="com.plugins.SecurityPluginConfiguration"/>
</property>
```

Then I implemented "SecurityPluginConfiguration" :

```
public class SecurityPluginConfiguration implements PluginConfiguration {

    public Class<? extends PluginProvider> providerClass() {
        return SecurityPluginProvider.class;
    }       
}
```

and "SecurityPluginProvider" :

```
public class SecurityPluginProvider  implements PluginProvider<SecurityPluginConfiguration>{


    @Override
    public String name() {
        System.out.println("%%%% Plugin Name : WhiteListSecurity %%%%%%");
        return "WhiteListSecurity";
    }

    @Override
    public String version() {
        return "1.0.0";
    }

    @Override
    public void start(PluginContext arg0) throws IgniteCheckedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(" %%%%%%  Starting Security Plugin Provider %%%%%%% ");

    }

     @Nullable
     @Override
     public Object createComponent(PluginContext ctx, Class cls) {

         System.out.println(" %%%%%%  Create Component HERE!!! %%%%%%% ");
            if (cls.isAssignableFrom(GridSecurityProcessor.class)) {
                return new WhiteListSecurityProcessor();
            } else {
                return null;
            } 
     }
.....

// other methods
}
```

When I am starting Ignite Node I don't see anything in the log file what I am trying to print out. It seems that 
start() or onIgniteStart() methods are not being invoked.

I added
org.apache.ignite.plugin.PluginProvider 
file to the META-INF directory and it contains 
com.plugins.SecurityPluginConfiguration

Do I miss anything? Is there any clear example of plugin implementation?

The issue was partially resolved by placing "org.apache.ignite.plugin.PluginProvider" file in "resources/META-INF/services" directory.

Now on the startup I am getting this error :

Failed to start grid: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.ignite.plugin.PluginProvider: Provider com.plugins.SecurityPluginConfiguration not a subtype

Comment: Did you get it working? Care to post a solution?

Comment: Nope, decided to go different way